# perl can't find modules installed by apt

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to build a perl program from source. The program has a Build script which installs all the many dependencies by cpan by invoking `perl ./Build installdeps`. However, some of the dependencies can't be installed by cpan properly, namely Wx.

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, I've been able to workaround this by installing the necessary modules via apt. For Wx, for example, I can do `sudo apt install libalien-wxwidgets-perl libwx-perl` and then if I run `perl ./Build installdeps` or simply `cpan -i Wx`, cpan detects that Wx is already installed, and I can eventually run `./Build install` and the program will work with the dependencies installed by apt. But, on my main computer, I'm unable to do this. I can install all the same dependencies by apt, but cpan still thinks they're not installed

Comment: *"However, some of the dependencies can't be installed by cpan properly, namely Wx."* Which error messages do you get?

Comment: on installing Wx with cpan, I get an error like `
    wxWidgets minimum supported version 2.007001 is missing.
    You will need to re-run Makefile.PL after it is installed.
    You must install wxWidgets using Alien::wxWidgets.
  `. I also can't install Alien::wxWidgets itself. In the past, I was able to resolve this by just installing libalien-wxwidgets-perl and libwx-perl with apt, but that doesn't seem to be working on this system.

Comment: I just tested installing on Ubuntu 22.04, perl version 5.38 and `Alien::wxWidgets` installed without issues here. Then, I tried to install `Wx` and it compiled (`make`) but when running `make test` I got a single test failure for the XRC extension: https://metacpan.org/release/MDOOTSON/Wx-0.9932/source/ext/xrc/lib/Wx/XRC.pm which failed to load. I do not think this failure is critical

Comment: Did you do that with perl-5.38.0 via perlbrewm (since I think Ubuntu 22.04 uses perl-5.34.0 as its system perl). And then `cpan -i Alien::wxWidgets`, `cpan -i Wx`? I actually just tried that on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 and it didn't work. But I used perlbrew and cpan. I didn't try using system perl or downloading the module and running `make` manually.

Comment: I just reinstalled perl-5.38.0 by perlbrew and tried `cpanm Alien::wxWidgets` and I get not OK due to Net::SSLeay, IO::Socket::SSL,IO::Socket::SSL::Utils, and LWP::Protocol::https

Comment: update: I was able to install `Alien::wxWidgets` on ubuntu 22.04 by doing
`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`,
`cpanm Net::SSLeat`,
`cpanm Alien::wxWidgets`
Now I'm trying to install Wx itself...

Comment: nope... I always get an error like this:
`PropertyGrid.c:27187:49: error: call of overloaded ‘wxVariant(wxColour&)’ is ambiguous
27187 |                 wxVariant value = wxVariant(*col);
      |                                                 ^`

Comment: Ah, you should update your question to note that you are not using the system perl.  That was important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt install libalien-wxwidgets-perl` will install the module for the system `perl`. This is not what you intend to do. From the comments you posted and the behaviour you describe, I gather you want to install the module for a different `perl`. This is usually done using

```bash
cpan Alien::wxWidgets
```

Note that you need to use the `cpan` that was installed by the relevant `perl`. That's how it knows for which `perl` to install the module, so to speak. Use the full path if necessary. That said, it sounds like you are using the correct `cpan`, so this paragraph isn't applicable to you.

Now, you say `cpan Alien::wxWidgets` doesn't work for you. That may be, but that's a problem you'll need to address directly, not by installing the module using a different `perl`. One `perl` can't use a module built by a different `perl`.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

1. Unless they are sufficiently similar, including but not limited to same version and same or newer revision. But that's surely not the case here. Why would you have two identical `perl` on the same system.

Comment: Thank you. I see what is going on now. Only the system perl should see modules I installed by apt. 
I was able to get `Alien::wxWidgets` to install with perl-5.38.0, but I'm still having trouble getting `Wx` to install.
I would also be happy to get this program to run on my system perl, but that doesn't seem to be working either. Plus, I figured it would be better to do it with perlbrew so as not to need root, and not to add unecessary modules to my system perl.